# is there any difference between these two questions that are related to queries?

Tags: sql-server-2005

Hi My friend ask me these two questions and make my mind busy would you please help me that is there any different between these two questions or they are the same as each other? thanks

Consider that we have one table "Orders"

```
Orders table

OrderID  CustomerID  EmployeeID  Freight
1          VINET       5          32.31
2          Nima        3          13.31
3          VINET       6          14.03
4          Mina        4          19.01
5          Nima        4          14.52
.           .          .            .
.           .          .            .
.           .          .            .
```

those two questions:

```
1) Select the id of those customers that their Freight is more than average
2)Select  the name of those customers that their freight is more than average
```

please tell me that what is the difference between these two questions?
also the customer ID is the name of customers (this field is unique in the Customer table but not for Orders table)

Comment: I think only you can answer it no? If the name is the id then these questions are the same, if the id referes to another table and the real name is in there then the answer is no.

Comment: matin, please read your own question and clear it up. Do you want Freight per Order or SUM(Freight) per Customer/Employee?

Comment: And this smells like homework. If that is the case please add the Homework tag.

Comment: really I do not know my friend asked me and I do not know that it is his home work or not

Answer (score 2):

I am not that much familiar. According to my knowledge, I will answer for your question. I think that, the first question will return order id, customer id and employee id. The second question will return customer id.

Answer (score 1):

You have a **CustomerId** (char) and an **EmployeeId** (int). No CustomerName.

They appear not to be directly related so:

**Yes**, they are different (groups of records) and their **SUM(Freight)** will be different.

Comment: you mean for the first query I should return OrderID and for the second one returning the CustomerID?

Comment: What I acttuall1y meant is that your question is inconsistent with the example table. And OrderId does not play a role (when you want to sum the Freight).

Comment: really I can not get what you mean! please write your queries for each of these questions.please

Comment: matin, the problem is that we do not know what you mean. Read and correct your question.